# What is an Eternal Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

*This puzzle is based off the [What is a Word™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20word%E2%84%A2) and [What is a Phrase™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20phrase%E2%84%A2) series started by [JLee](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/463/jlee) and their spin-off [What is a Number™](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=what%20is%20a%20number%E2%84%A2) series.*

If a word conforms to a certain rule, I call it an Eternal Word™. Use the following examples to find the rule:

$$
% set Title text. (spaces around the text ARE important; do not remove.)
% increase Pad value only if your entries are longer than the title bar.
%
\def\Pad{\P{0.0}}  \def\Title{\textbf{ Eternal }}
%
\def\S#1#2{\Space{#1}{20px}{#2px}}\def\P#1{\V{#1em}}\def\V#1{\S{#1}{9}}
\def\T{\Title\textbf{Words}^{\;\!™}\Pad}\def\NT{\Pad\textbf{Not}\T\ }\displaystyle
\smash{\lower{29px}\bbox[yellow]{\phantom{\rlap{rubio.2019.05.15}\S{6px}{0}
\begin{array}{cc}\Pad\T&\NT\\\end{array}}}}\atop\def\V#1{\S{#1}{5}}
\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\Pad\T&\NT\\\hline
%
\text{ASKING}&\text{ANSWERING}\\ \hline
\text{ATARI}&\text{KONAMI}\\ \hline
\text{NINTENDO}&\text{SEGA}\\ \hline
\text{ASTEROIDS}&\text{PACMAN}\\ \hline
\text{RACHEL}&\text{MONICA}\\ \hline
\text{CHANDLER}&\text{PHOEBE}\\ \hline
\text{PINK}&\text{FUCHSIA}\\ \hline
\text{MAGENTA}&\text{LAVENDER}\\ \hline
\text{EARTH}&\text{PLUTO}\\ \hline
\text{DWARF}&\text{MIDGET}\\ \hline
\text{PLANET}&\text{PLANETOID}\\ \hline
\text{70}&\text{69}\\ \hline
\text{PROPER}&\text{IMPROPER}\\ \hline
\text{FACTORY}&\text{FACTOR}\\ \hline
\text{FLATTER}&\text{FATTER}\\ \hline
\end{array}$$

---

The puzzle satisfies the series' inbuilt assumption, that each word can be tested for whether it is an Eternal Word™ without relying on the other words.

These are not the only examples, there are more of both Eternal Words™ and Not Eternal Words™.

CSV version:

```
ASKING,    ANSWERING
ATARI,     KONAMI
NINTENDO,  SEGA
ASTEROIDS, PACMAN
RACHEL,    MONICA
CHANDLER,  PHOEBE
PINK,      FUCHSIA
MAGENTA,   LAVENDER
EARTH,     PLUTO
DWARF,     MIDGET
PLANET,    PLANETOID
70,        69
PROPER,    IMPROPER
FACTORY,   FACTOR
FLATTER,   FATTER
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

An Eternal Word™ is

> a word where you can remove the first and last letter to produce another word.
>
>  ASKING → SKIN
>  ATARI → TAR
>  NINTENDO → INTEND
>  ASTEROIDS → STEROID
>  RACHEL → ACHE
>  CHANDLER → HANDLE
>  PINK → IN
>  MAGENTA → AGENT
>  EARTH → ART
>  DWARF → WAR
>  PLANET → LANE
>  SEVENTY → EVENT
>  PROPER → ROPE
>  FACTORY → ACTOR
>  FLATTER → LATTE

The name:

> "Eternal" means "without end", and you can make new words by removing both ends of an Eternal Word™.

Comment: that was fast. +1

Comment: (+1): wow, well done! :P

Comment: How is 70 eternal then?

Comment: @Eugene Perhaps rot13(Friragl → rirag)?

Comment: @Eugene I suspect it's meant to be spelled out as SEVENTY